# Пунктуация при одиночном определении

Tags: пунктуация, определения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли обособлять "обессиленный"?

"Не успел он сделать несколько шагов, как () обессиленный () упал на колени".

Если было бы "обессиленно", то все понятно. В примере же выше, думаю, запятые нужны. По тому же принципу, как здесь: "Обессиленный, он упал", "Счастливый, он вышел из дома".

Скажите, пожалуйста, верно ли это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: *Не успел он сделать несколько шагов, как, **обессиленный**, упал на колени.*

**Пояснение**

**1. Теория**

Эта тема рассмотрена  [у Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109)

**Пункт 2 (3).** Не обособляются определения, связанные по смыслу не только с подлежащим, **но и со сказуемым**, в состав которого они входят: *В марте зерно **лежало ссыпанное** в закрома.*

**Пункт 10.** Определение, относящееся **к личному местоимению**, обособляется независимо от степени его распространенности и местоположения: Он повернулся и ушёл, а **я, растерянный**, остался рядом с девочкой в пустой жаркой степи (Пауст.);

**Примечание.**  Не обособляется определение **при личном местоимении**: 1) если определение по смыслу связано не только с подлежащим-местоимением, но и со сказуемым : **Он** выходит из задних комнат уже **окончательно расстроенный** (Гонч.);

**2. Решение задачи:**

*Не успел он сделать несколько шагОв, как, **обессиленный**, упал на колЕни.*

Заданное предложение не совсем стандартной конструкции, оно содержит **однородные сказуемые,** связанные противительно-уступительными отношениями (хотя он сделал всего несколько шагов, но уже обессилел и упал).

Одиночное определение **не входит в состав сказуемого** (нет тесной связи, что видно по его позиции), и обособляется.

Но при постановке определения **в конец предложения** такая связь будет обозначена и обособления нет: *Не успел он сделать несколько шагОв, как **упал** на колени **обессИленный.***

Comment: Большое спасибо за подробное разъяснение! :)